# Is there more way for cors blocked?

Tags: javascript, html, linux

I'm going to use a [this qr-scanner library](https://github.com/nimiq/qr-scanner) for my project. I wanted to test demo locally at first, so I create a folder and copy index.html and qr-scanner.min.js and qr-scanner-worker.min.js from the zip file that i downloaded from the library and run locally. My directory structure is

```
      /nimiqQrScanner
         index.html
         qr-scanner.min.js
         qr-scanner-worker.min.js
```

my operating system is ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
my browser is firefox
and error is

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///home/khinyu/my_shits/html%20files/qr-scanner.min.js. (Reason: CORS request not http).
```

I tried with cors block extensions, add-ons and also tried this commmand

```
$ google-chrome --disable-web-security --user-data-a-dir=/home/khinyu/.config/google-chrome
```

and don't work at all. pls help me. really sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Are you accessing `index.html` as a file directly? Or using a local http server?

Comment: You're loading it with `file://` instead of `http://` protocol.  Use an actual HTTP server instead of loading using the file system.

Comment: yes, u both are right. I was just loading the file on browser and now I use the lamp local server and the library works good. Really thanks u guys both. I can breathe easily now.